# Lightbox + jQuery conflict

Tags: jquery, html, firefox, lightbox

`Lightbox` is not working anymore after I made a tab navigation using `jQuery`..
`Chrome` visualization is fine, but in `Firefox` is a mess.

I'm doing something wrong since `event.preventDefault();` and `return false` are not working (I had to use a scroll to move back to the bottom of the page after clicking an anchor `a href="#id_name` for the tab controller)

Any help would be appreciated.

Head:

```
 <!-- Lightbox + Prototype + jQuery -->     
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/prototype.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/scriptaculous.js?load=effects,builder"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/lightbox.js"></script>
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
      if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') { document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='js/jquery-1.8.0.min.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E")); }
 </script>
```

jQuery for Tab Navigation:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        //Default Action
        $(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all content
        $("ul.bmenu li:first").addClass("active").show(); //Activate first tab
        $(".tab_content:first").show(); //Show first tab content                     

        //On Click Event
        $("ul.bmenu li").click(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault(); //non impedisce di scrollare to Top
            $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, "slow");
            $("ul.bmenu li").removeClass("active"); //Remove any "active" class
            $(this).addClass("active"); //Add "active" class to selected tab
            $(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all tab content
            var activeTab = $(this).find("a").attr("href"); //Find the rel attribute value to identify the active tab + content
            $(activeTab).fadeIn(); //Fade in the active content
            return false; //non impedisce di scrollare to Top
        });                                  
    });
</script>
```

Some of the HTML:

```
<div class="tab_content content" id="tab2">
    <div class="images_grid"> <!-- images_grid_collezione -->
        <!-- Riga 1 -->
        <a href="imgs_grid/Rosso_01.png" rel="lightbox[medardo_rosso]"><img class="grid_img" src="imgs_grid/Rosso_01.png" alt="" /></a>
        <a href="imgs_grid/Rosso_02.png" rel="lightbox[medardo_rosso]"><img class="grid_img" src="imgs_grid/Rosso_02.png" alt="" /></a>
```

I uploaded the website in a temporary directory [here](http://www.picbattle.net/websites/Sito%20Medardo%20Rosso%20IN_PROGRESS/index_Tabs.html).

Answer (score 0):

Place  `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>` 
at the very first line in the header

Comment: Thanks, but that way the tab navigation breaks (don't know why to be honest)

Answer (score 0):

the problem is you are including the `jquery` at the last and other libraries that depend upon jquery, prior to jquery. Order does matter include it in the begining and you should be fine

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/prototype.js"></script>   
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/lightbox.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
        if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') { document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='js/jquery-1.8.0.min.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E")); }
 </script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/scriptaculous.js?load=effects,builder"></script>
```

Comment: @AndreaVaccarella you have javascript errors on the page try removing them first

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using the jQuery noConflict mode.
Long story short: prototype short notation "$" was in conflict with jQuery short notation "$".

Add "jQuery.noConflic()" at the beginning of the script and replace the "$" with "jQuery" or simply add a variable (I used "j").

`$j(document).ready(function() {
$j(".tab_content").hide(); //Some Other actions
...`

problem solved.Thanks everybody for the help! :)